# OS X Yosemite : Impossible to install cocoapods

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cocoapods, osx-yosemite, osx-yosemite-beta

I have ruby version : ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-darwin13.0]
When I try install cocoapods i get :

```
$ sudo gem install cocoapods -V

ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'cocoapods' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - no such name (https://api.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
GET https://api.rubygems.org/prerelease_specs.4.8.gz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET https://s3.amazonaws.com/production.s3.rubygems.org/prerelease_specs.4.8.gz
200 OK
GET https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET https://s3.amazonaws.com/production.s3.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz
200 OK
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: cocoapods
```

Someone to help me solve this?

Comment: I already tried this and get `gem update --system
Latest version currently installed. Aborting.` then `gem install cocoapods
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::UnknownHostError)
    no such name (https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=cocoapods-trunk)`

Comment: You probably need to reinstall Ruby

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It appears that at this day HomeBrew has few issues with OSX Yosemite.
I solved my issue by deleting ruby using the command :

```
brew uninstall ruby
```

and then installing rvm and ruby again with RVM:

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
rvm rubygems latest
```

then `gem install cocoapods` worked like a charm !

Comment: After the curl, I used: `source /Users/anthonyjmay/.rvm/scripts/rvm` then `rvm rubygems latest --force`, then `sudo gem install xcodeproj`, and finally `sudo gem install cocoapods` Appears this issue is related to the ruby upgrade in Yosemite.

Comment: Thanks Sancho!  And Thank you amay0048 for complementing this answer. Works great!

Comment: Nice one Sancho and ama0048! Following both your steps worked.

Comment: still not working for me. Terminal code stuck at line **GET https://api.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/xcodeproj-0.26.1.gemspec.rz
302 Moved Temporarily**

Answer (score 0):

```
brew install ruby
```

can do the work too, after that

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

It did worked in my yosemite